# Can I preview skins in-game (weapons, abilities) before purchasing them?

Tags: overwatch

**Is there a way to perhaps try out any skin in the game without paying for them**? Essentially, what I'm looking for is a way to preview a skin without purchasing them, as coins are hard to come by and I'd like to be content with a skin before buying it.

I don't want to look at just the visuals. The Torbjorn skins don't show what his Turret will look like, only his Rivet Gun, and I can't find a way so far to preview them.

Is there a way to preview the in-game skins, such as weapon models and ability looks?

Comment: I don't want to look at just visuals. The Torbjorn skins don't show what his Turret will look like, only his Rivet Gun, and I can't find a way so far to preview them.  I'm not asking where the skins are located

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see all the skins by clicking on "Hero Gallery" in the menu, then click on the hero you want, then "Skins" and see a preview of all their skins by clicking on it. Furthermore, you can rotate them by holding left mouse button and moving your mouse.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I'm asking if there's a way to preview what the skins look like in-game, not from the hero gallery

Comment: What's the difference ? They're exactly the same in-game and in Hero Gallery. I would understand your request in League of Legends for example, where all you have as a preview is a splash art, but in Overwatch you have the 3D model, so...

Comment: What are you talking about? How can I see what my turret looks like in-game with the Hero Gallery, or with other abilities? How can I see what Hanzo's ult looks like? You can't see his ult in hero gallery, unless I"m missing something

Comment: Oh, forgot this aspect, sorry. Unfortunately you can't see any preview of it for the moment, except by browsing it on the web :/